# Getting runtime error for unknown reason; referencing ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, oop, runtime-error

I'm trying to make a program that stores an array of a class I've denoted as entry. This class stores a the user's input based on command, name, number, and a note. After the entry is received it is to be sent to a file, through the ObjectInput/ObjectOutput, and stores for later use.

Sort of like a simple contact list that can be periodically called and updated from time to time.

I'm running into a sort of weird error(seen below). If anyone could help me fix this error I would greatly appreciate it.

Code:

```
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class phonebook {

    protected Entry[] entryList = new Entry[200];

    protected int length = 0;

    public void doList() {
        for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
            System.out.print(entryList[i]);
        }
    }

    public void doAddEntry(Entry entry) throws Exception {
        if (length == 200) {
            throw new Exception("I'm full");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
            if (entryList[i].name.compareToIgnoreCase(entry.name) <0) {
                //?
            }
        }
    }

    public void doFind(String term) {
        // look for input in entryList's name fields
    }

    public void doSave() throws Exception {
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("contacts.txt"));
        os.writeObject(entryList);
        os.close();
    }


    public void doLoad() throws Exception {
       ***ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("contacts.txt"));***
        entryList = (Entry[])oin.readObject();
        oin.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String line;
    String[] command;
    Scanner input;
    String delimeter;
    delimeter = " ";
    phonebook pbook;
    String cmd;
    String term;

    pbook = new phonebook();
    cmd= "";
    input=new Scanner (System.in);
    **pbook.doLoad();**
    System.out.println("Codes are entered as 1 to 8 characters");
    System.out.println("Use \"e\" for enter, \"f\" for find, \"l\" to list, and \"q\" to quit");
    System.out.println();

    do {
    System.out.print("Command: ");
    line = input.nextLine();
    command = line.split(delimeter);
    if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("e")) {
        Entry e = new Entry();
        e.name = command[0];
        System.out.print("Enter Number: ");
        e.number=input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Notes:  ");
        e.notes=input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("");
            pbook.doAddEntry(e);
        } else if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("f")) {
            term=command[0];
            pbook.doFind(term);
            } else if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {
                pbook.doList(); 
                } else if (command[0].equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                System.out.println("Exiting Program...");
                pbook.doSave();
                break;
                    } else { 
                        System.out.println("Invalid Command");
                        continue;
                    } 
    } while (true);
    }
    }
```

Class:

```
 public class Entry implements java.io.Serializable {
    public String name;
    public String number;
    public String notes;    
}
```

Compiler Error Message (code referencing error can be found inbetween *** above):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at phonebook.doLoad(phonebook.java:39)
    at phonebook.main(phonebook.java:57)
```

Comment: That is not a compiler error, it is a runtime error. Looks like contacts.txt is empty.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel & Perception Thanks guys I'll update the title, and can confirm that I haven't fatfingered, I just had an issue when pasting my code into the original post.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel contacts.txt is empty because I haven't put anything in it. This program should take input and store it in the file for later use but isn't helping.

Comment: What happens when contacts.txt isn't empty?

Comment: @pamphlet runtime error as well

Comment: You can't expect to an object (without an Exception) from a file you haven't saved an object to, at some point in the past.  That is, you must have previously called `doSave()` before you can call `doLoad()`.  Some simple exception handling in your `doLoad()` method should do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you confirm that `contacts.txt` is empty. That is the reason that `EOFException` is thrown. The [`ObjectOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [`ObjectInputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) use a very specific protocol and format that includes a serialization streamheader that the `ObjectInputStream` expects to be present when constructed. As the file is empty it can't read that header and an `EOFException` is thrown when it attempts to read beyond the end of the file.

You simply cannot use an empty file when using `ObjectInputStream`. So if you need it to work with an empty file, then you should not be using `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream`, but write your own text (or binary format) files. Eg with a [`BufferedWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) and a [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and/or [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Alternatively, you need to be prepared to handle this `EOFException` in your `doLoad` method and return an empty array or null.